# Capturing powershell warning

Tags: powershell, warnings, exchange-server

I am trying to capture the warning that gets thrown if I try to remove mailbox permissions from a mailbox for someone who doesn't have permissions in the first place.

```
#$WarningPreference = "continue"
try
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "test2" -User "test1" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$False | Out-File c:\temp\output2.txt -Encoding ASCII
}
catch
{
#Write-Warning -Message $($_.Exception.Message) 3 > c:\temp\warning.txt
}
```

There is no output in either output2.txt or warning.txt - what am I doing wrong?

The warnings I am trying to capture appear in yellow and say:

```
WARNING: The cmdlet extension agent with the index 0 has thrown an exception in OnComplete(). The exception is:
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ExchangePrincipal.get_ServerFullyQualifiedDomainName()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.Initialize(MapiStore linkedStore, LogonType logonType,
ExchangePrincipal owner, DelegateLogonUser delegateUser, Object identity, OpenMailboxSessionFlags flags,
GenericIdentity auxiliaryIdentity)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateMailboxSession>b__10(MailboxSession
mailboxSession)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.InternalCreateMailboxSession(LogonType logonType,
ExchangePrincipal owner, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, IAccountingObject budget, Action`1
initializeMailboxSession, InitializeMailboxSessionFailure initializeMailboxSessionFailure)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.ConfigurableOpen(ExchangePrincipal mailbox, MailboxAccessInfo
accessInfo, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String clientInfoString, LogonType logonType, PropertyDefinition[]
mailboxProperties, InitializationFlags initFlags, IList`1 foldersToInit, IAccountingObject budget)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MailboxSession.OpenAsSystemService(ExchangePrincipal mailboxOwner, CultureInfo
cultureInfo, String clientInfoString)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.MailboxLoggerFactory.XsoMailer.Log(AdminLogMessageData data,
LogMessageDelegate logMessage)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.ProvisioningAgent.AdminLogProvisioningHandler.OnComplete(Boolean succeeded, Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Provisioning.ProvisioningLayer.OnComplete(Task task, Boolean succeeded, Exception exception)
WARNING: Can't remove the access control entry on the object "CN=xxxxx" for account "xxxxx" because the ACE doesn't exist on the
object.
```

Thanks for all the help so far!  My code now looks like this:

```
$WarningPreference = "continue"
try
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "test1" -User "test2" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$False 2> c:\temp\errors.txt 3> c:\temp\warnings.txt -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
2> c:\temp\errors.txt
}
```

***FINAL SOLUTION - THANKS ALL ***

```
$WarningPreference = "continue"
try
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "test1" -User test2" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$False 2> c:\temp\errors.txt 3> c:\temp\warnings.txt -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
$_ > c:\temp\errors.txt
}
```

Comment: `2>c:\temp\errors.txt` -> `$_ > c:\temp\errors.txt` - `$_` represents the exception at hand. (What `2>c:\temp\errors.txt`  does is to send integer `2` (stringified) via the success output stream to the file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the question's generic title, let me first recap **how capturing warnings works *in general***:

- In a *file* such as `warnings.txt`: with `3> warnings.txt`

  - To *suppress* warnings ad hoc: `3> $null`
- In a *variable* such as `$warnings`: with `-WarningVariable warnings` (`-wv warnings`)

  - However, that *still passes the warnings through* and therefore prints them, so in order to prevent that you must *also* use `3> $null` or `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue`.

Note that these constructs must be applied to the very command producing the warnings, as (by default) only the *success* output stream (the stream with index `1`) is sent through the pipeline:

```
# OK - saves warnings to file 'warnings.txt' without printing them.
Do-Stuff 3> warnings.txt | Out-File out.txt

# INCORRECT - still prints warnings, because they are NOT sent through the 
#             pipeline, and then creates empty file 'warnings.txt', because
#             Out-File itself produces no warnings.
Do-Stuff | Out-File out.txt 3> warnings.txt
```

---

As for **what you tried:**

> There is no output in either output2.txt or warning.txt

- Presumably, there is no output in `output2.txt`, because the `Remove-MailboxPermission` has not produced any *success* output yet at the time it throws an exception. When the exception occurs, control is instantly transferred to `catch` handler, so the pipeline is stopped right there, and `Out-File` never receives input from `Remove-MailboxPermission`'s success stream.

  - Note that `try` / `catch` only takes effect if `Remove-MailboxPermission` produces a statement-*terminating* error by default; to also make it take effect for *non-terminating* errors, add `-ErrorAction Stop`.
    If the `Remove-MailboxPermission` produces *just* warnings - and no error at all - then `try` / `catch` won't have any effect.
- There is no output in `warning.txt` (even with the line re-activated by removing the initial `#`), because `try` / `catch` only catches *error* output, not *warnings*; that is, the warnings *have already printed* by the time the `catch` handler is processed.

Answer (score 4):

Add `-WarningAction Stop` or `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Remove-MailboxPermission` command:

```
try
{
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "test2" -User "test1" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$False -WarningAction Stop -ErrorAction Stop | Out-File c:\temp\output2.txt -Encoding ASCII
}
catch
{
#Write-Warning -Message $($_.Exception.Message) 3 > c:\temp\warning.txt
}
```

Comment: -ErrorAction Stop was an important piece of the jigsaw in this case.  I am Ok in this case to keep going if there is a warning as the warning is not serious :)  Thank you!

Comment: For those who are actually trying to handle "Warnings" that are returned from various commands such as those found in the IISAdministration or WebAdministration modules,  -WarningAction is the solution. For that reason +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the -WarningAction and -WarningVariable common parameters to capture the warning to a variable and cause it to not show to the console.

```
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity "test2" -User "test1" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$False | Out-File c:\temp\output2.txt -Encoding ASCII -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -WarningVariable CapturedWarning
```

Then, `$CapturedWarning` should have the warning in it.

Comment: I am still getting the yellow warning but when I try and display the contents of the CapturedWarning variable it is empty.

Comment: echo "warning: $CapturedWarning"

Comment: Strange.  I can't test your specific cmdlet, but creating a "test" function that just writes a warning shows that this technique works fine in that it captures the warning in a variable and it's not written to the console.