# azure devops build task warning in powershell using dbatools

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, warnings, dacpac, dbatools

I have a azure devops powershell build task that is throwing warnings however, I am not sure how to capture those warning in the build logs.

```
2018-10-31T18:19:37.9619067Z WARNING: [13:19:37][Publish-DbaDacPackage] Deployment failed | DropExtendedPropertiesNotInSource conflicts with the 
2018-10-31T18:19:37.9621270Z selected DoNotDropObjectType ExtendedProperties
```

Example Code:

```
try
    {
        $dacpac = "$($ArtifactPath)\DatabaseProjects\$($db)\bin\$($BuildConfig)\$($db).dacpac"
        $publishProfile = "$($ArtifactPath)\DatabaseProjects\$($db)\$($db).publish.xml"
        Publish-DbaDacPackage -SqlInstance $Sql -Database $db -Path $dacpac -PublishXml $publishProfile -GenerateDeploymentScript -ScriptOnly -OutputPath $OutPath

    }  
Catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
            Write-Host "  The database: $($db) failed during process. See error message here: $($ErrorMessage)."
            Write-Host "    Failed item: $($FailedItem)"
        }
```

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: could you try [`-WarningAction Stop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378174/7073340)